# How can I cancel all accepted requests or list them in here batch api?

Tags: here-api

One of our our batch requests is holding up the queue so that all subsequent requests never transition past accepted. We need to flush the queue but the only api call I see on the documentation is for deleteing a job request by specifying its job ID. Is there a way to delete all job requests or list job ids so that we can then delete the one by one? If there isn't is there a way for the Here team to clear our queue?

Answer (score 0):

For each job request you send, you get a request ID back. With this ID, you can cancel (terminate) or delete (remove) the job. Currently the batch geocoder API does not support cancelling or deleting all jobs in a single request. This has to be done one after the other for each request (by specifying the request ID).

Example request to cancel a job:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/example-cancel.html

Comment: I am aware of how to cancel a single job as I mentioned in my question. I asked if there isn't a way to cancel all is there a way to get a list of all job ids to cancel them one by one.

Comment: No like I said, the API currently does not support cancelling/listing all jobs at time.